# Running react-native run-ios launches the app but close after splash, but via Xcode works perfectly

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am developing a React Native app. Since last week, I don't know why, I cannot run my app via `react-native run-ios` because the app just close after splash is shown.

Conversely, if I run the application from Xcode it works perfectly. In Android works perfectly too.

I need to run it via `react-native run-ios` to debug, someone have an idea what could be happening?

This problem has occurred after update my macOS from Sierra (not High Sierra) to Mojave.

[image]
EDIT: When this screen appear, it don't let a second to response, automatically the app close itself, and I cannot activate the debug mode to try see something in the console, the Node console of the server don't seems show anything weird, all is like it should be.

Comment: Could you debug your crash? Can you paste any details about it?

Comment: I can not, I do not have time to activate the debugging because it closes before.

Comment: When the green label 'Loading from localhost: 8081' is appearing instantly the app close itself with no error or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reach to debug the app from `Xcode` changing `schema` from `Release` to `Debug`.

Anyway I could reach open it with the command `react-native run-ios`.

The steps to change schema are those:
`Product` -> `Scheme` -> `Edit Scheme` and select `Debug` instead of `Release`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar errors, for me it was enough to re-run pod install, clean cache, restart simulator and temporarily disable the debugger.

1) Clean all the cache:

`rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-* && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf node_modules && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`

2) re-run `pod install` in the ios folder

3) restart the simulator or try to change the simulator:

`react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 7"`

4) After app starts installing on simulator immediately run a `CMD+D` and disable debugger

If you get any error with cocoaPods try re-installing them:

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

The error your are getting for cocoapods should be fixed with a simple re-install.

Update: I was able to replicate this on device, the only workaround to I found to load content was to disable the debugger and using console.warn to debug things. On simulator restarting JS server and disable&&enable the debugger seems to fix any issue.
I will update my answer if I will find a better solution.

Comment: When i try to re-run pod install i get this message from the terminal: 
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: `sudo gem update --system`
`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Comment: I correct the errors, sorry for the late response. Anyway, after correct the error I got I am facing the same problem before.

Comment: Do you get any errors/warnings at build? Can you add your package.json content here? Does pod install command work now?

Comment: No I don't. But, I've noticed that when I build with the command react-native run-ios to open it from simulator, in the building messages I get this:  Signing Identity:     "-". And when I do  react-native run-ios --configuration Debug --device "iPhone of Khalil" that is where I can debug, doing it by my physical device the Signing Identity is: "iPhone Developer: khalil@******(I won't put here my credentials) ". So it could be something about the sign identity is wrong in the simulator, the problem would be from here. Can you think of something?

Comment: From what I understand the issue is related to simulator and the communication between the debugger and the simulator. Try to completely uninstall the app from the simulator, change simulator, clean cache and restart the JS server. Does the app start now on simulator if you turn off the debugger?

Comment: I have done all of that :(. I'm thinking about the problem is that, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I'll give you the points due the help you tried to give me although we couldn't get the real solution. Thank you so much for help.